# How this symbol is pronounced

Tags: neural-networks

For now I read book [Neural networks and learning machines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131471392). Inside of that book is unknown for me symbol. How it should be pronounced? I didn't find it on [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) or at other articles. 
PS I know what is conditional probability. I just want to know how this strange character should be pronounced

[image]

Comment: Its $\LaTeX$ command is \mathscr{c}, so I guess "script c". Not sure though, never seen it used before.

Comment: That looks like a  script or calligraphy C, pronounced *"...from class C"*.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58124/4386 has more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's "script C" (or also "curly C" I think).

http://www.charbase.com/1d49e-unicode-mathematical-script-capital-c